# CalendarKit "Calendar App" would like to access your calendar , authorization pop-up not working

Tags: calendarkit

Testing the CalendarApp sample code
https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarApp 1.1.17
Xcode 15.0.1

Built and attached to IOS 17 on iPhone 13, however the events don't populate.

Error (1,013) in reply block for CADDatabaseFetchCalendarItemsWithPredicate attempt 1/3
Type: Error | Timestamp: 2023-11-05 10:04:50.540960-08:00 | Library: EventKit | Subsystem: com.apple.eventkit | Category: EventKit | TID: 0x13304d

Thanks
J

The app does load in the viewcontroller, but the permission to access calendar pop-up next shows up.

Comment: Hi, you need to allow CalendarApp to access your calendar in order to view events.

Comment: In the CalendarViewController code, Looks like eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) is a deprecated function in IOS 17, and should be using eventStore.requestFullAccessToEvents(completion: )

Comment: Added this piece of code for IOS 17

if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
                eventStore.requestFullAccessToEvents { [weak self] granted, error in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //guard let self else { return }
                        self!.initializeStore()
                        self!.subscribeToNotifications()
                        self!.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                
            }

Comment: Is this some sort of new API for iOS 17? Could you please also file an issue in the repository as well?

Comment: Sure, I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to transition to the newer iOS 17+ API: [TN3152: Migrating to the latest Calendar access levels](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3152-migrating-to-the-latest-calendar-access-levels)

The CalendarApp has been updated: [Update to iOS 17 EventKit API, #7](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarApp/commit/a8b8eef69a26d555c449cc74682b862efc9608ac), feel free to use the app starting with version 2.6.0